# Duplicate Content Question - SEO

Tags: seo, nofollow

I have an online store with different categories in the main navigatio.  Ie.  Category A, Category B etc.

I also have a link in the main nav called 'Sale Items'.  It points to a page which lists items which are on sale from both Category A and Category B.

Should I add a rel="nofollow" tag to the Sale Items link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about SEO

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it.

If you add the rel="nofollow" tag, the tag is only a suggestion.  You cannot actually stop the search engine from indexing the sales page.

You may want to consider using the canonical relationship.  However, I would think you would want both the sales page and the category indexed.

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html

Comment: thanks!  I'm using canonical links.  I've leave it without the nofollow in this case.